# Network tcp socket application retry method

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a windows based client(c++) and server(c#) application which will communicate to each other via tcp packets. Here the client is sending data and server needs to acknowledge the same.

Now for this purpose I have made one single 'socket()' and 'connect()' call during the client lifetime on its startup. Some error checking and retries has been kept inside 'send()' and 'recv()' calling methods. Do note that one client will send one set (multiple packets) of data and quit at a time.

Now my questions are:

> 1. If the server is running continuously(e.g. windows service) on some PC, do I really need to consider about connection
>      breakdown(network failure) and creating a new socket and connect
>      accordingly from client?
> 2. If that be so, shall I need to consider resending the data from starting or from the point where client has failed to communicate last
>      time?

I want to know the general methods what people are using around the world for dealing this kind of situations for network applications.

Answer (score 0):

> do I really need to consider about connection breakdown and creating a new socket and connect accordingly from client?

Depends on how precious your data is. If you want to make sure it ended up at the server, and an error occurred while sending, then you can consider it "not sent".

> If that be so, shall I need to consider resending the data from starting or from the point where client has failed to communicate last time?

That depends entirely on how your application logic and application protocol work. From your description we can't know how you send your data and how a server would recognize data it has already seen.

Answer (score 0):

> do I really need to consider about connection breakdown(network
>   failure) and creating a new socket and connect accordingly from
>   client?

You do certainly not need to create a new socket after connection shutdown; you can use the existing socket to connect anew.